# Remove multiple items in filter method React/JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have to manipulate two arrays. And I have some issues with removing multiply items.
Let assume we have two arrays:

`const [array1, setArray1] = useState([1,3,5])`

`const [array2, setArray2] = useState([2,4,6])`

And there is a function for one of them to remove number from array:

`const someArray = [4]`

`const toArray1 = (someArray) => { setArray2(array2.filter(e => e !== someArray[0]))`

This code works if one element is removed from array, however I would like to obtain that I can remove multiply numbers from array. For example `const someArray = [2,4,6]` allows me to get `array2 = []`

I wonder is there is a good way to chain filter and map (or forEach) to filter all values from given array.

Comment: I forget to mention it's React question with hooks. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for a check with an array.

```
array2.filter(e => !someArray.includes(e))
```

Comment: @AndrewL64 I know, I have to wait some time before I can accept solution. Thank you for letting me know.